# How to kill a smach state machine inside an ActionServerWrapper

Tags: actionlib, smach

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there!

I can't find a way to kill an action server I have created using smach and its [action server wrapper](http://www.ros.org/wiki/smach/Tutorials/Wrapping%20a%20SMACH%20Container%20With%20actionlib).
Once the action server is started (`my_action_server_wrapper.run_server()`), I'm not able to kill it using "ctrl + c".

I tried "try + except" without luck. Currently I'm starting a second instance with the same name, what makes the first one stop. But this is not really a suitable solution.

Thanks for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53764/how-to-kill-a-smach-state-machine-inside-an-actionserverwrapper/) by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2062 on 2013-01-30

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`my_action_server_wrapper.run_server()` is a non-blocking call that starts the server (including a background thread, which is why your program isn't exiting). If you'd like to be able to ctrl-c your program, then you need something to wait in the main thread, handle the signal, and then signal rospy to shutdown.

Just add the following after your call to `my_action_server_wrapper.run_server()`:

```
rospy.spin()
```

This will block until you ctrl-c your program, at which point it will call `rospy.signal_shutdown()`. For more on this, see the rospy documentation on [Initialization and Shutdown](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rospy/Overview/Initialization%20and%20Shutdown#Shutting_down).

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2013-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-01-30**:
Yeha! Things can be so easy - what a pleasure! :-) Thanks a lot!

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-01-30**:
PS: This information and "fix" might be a good addition to the tutorial, since I guess most people would like to shutdown their server from time to time. ;-)

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2013-01-31**:
Done. http://www.ros.org/wiki/smach/Tutorials/Wrapping%20a%20SMACH%20Container%20With%20actionlib?action=diff&rev1=21&rev2=22